Does anyone know if Edit Mode's "Make Line" Tool was deleted or moved in Blender 4.2?
I used the tool in previous versions of Blender. I believe it is a default tool, since I've checked all my add-ons and they appear to be up-to-date.
The image below is an expanded view of where the tool is located and what the icon looks like in Blender 4.1


Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. Your previous question was closed for lack of clarity and you just copied similar content here instead of editing the post. The proper way to go is to edit your previous question and then it is automatically queued up for reopening.

Based on the previous post I made about this issue, I could not have been more clear. Try reading to understand the problem, rather than to simply respond.

I asked you to post an image of the expanded view (which you did), and then we could have reopened the question. However, you decided to delete it and created a new post instead of waiting for it to be reopened. Please do not create duplicate posts in the future. And please don't forget to click the checkmark to the answer post that helped you resolve your problem. Thank you.

It seems to be from the addon Snap Utilities Line:
Snap Utilities Line - Blender 4.2 Manual
Like most addons that used to be shipped with Blender out of the box, they are now to be downloaded from the extensions platform, which you can do directly from Blender:

More about the new extensions platform on 4.2 LTS Release Notes - Extensions — blender.org

Thanks for the help, lauloque

@mrabysmal if this has helped resolve your problem, please mark the check mark to the left of this post so we can close this question.
